# LoginRequiredMixin fails but user is authenticated

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, react-native-fetch-blob

I am using django rest framework token authentication for authenticating a user. When I hit a request with react-native-fetch-blob with header as

```
{
    Authorization : token,
    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
    'Range' : 'bytes=22976-'
}
```

and use `LoginRequiredMixin` in my server code it fails and redirects. If I remove the `LoginRequiredMixin` it passes and `request.user.is_authenticated()` gives `True`. How do I authenticate the user with the restriction that the user is logged in?
Is there any specific header that I am missing from the request?

Comment: Can you confirm you actually pass the token?

Comment: Yes, request.META gives the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header along with the token

Answer (score 3):

`LoginRequiredMixin` is a pure Django thing and will only work with Session authentication. Since you're doing token auth, it won't work and will consider you're not logged in and therefore will redirect you.

Django REST framework provides its own authentication and permission system. It's the latter you'll be interested in in particular the [IsAuthenticated](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) permission check.

Comment: What do I need to pass along the request for Session authentication? React-native fetch does the authentication. Is there any header that I can send along with the request?

Comment: I'm missing a point here. Why would you use both the session authentication along with the token authentication ? Why don't you just use one ?

Comment: I am already using session authentication for the APIs and I want to reuse few of them.

Comment: few ? Why do you use a token authentication then ?

Comment: Lets not get away from the point. I am using token authentication for my necessities. What I am asking is for session authentication from a react native app what should I do or am I missing any header?

Comment: For what I get, your issue is your trying to double authenticate your users which will not be working.

Answer (score 2):

regards. Based @kaushikdr comment I wrote this mixin that allows both session authentication with login required + token authentication:

https://gist.github.com/jsmedmar/d846eee063fa23148f8a87313dd590a3

```
from django.contrib.auth import mixins
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import generics

class TokenLoginRequiredMixin(mixins.LoginRequiredMixin):

    """A login required mixin that allows token authentication."""

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """If token was provided, ignore authenticated status."""
        http_auth = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")

        if http_auth and "Token" in http_auth:
            pass

        elif not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return self.handle_no_permission()

        return super(mixins.LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)

class ListAPIView(TokenLoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListAPIView):

    """This view suppot both token and session authentication."""

    authentication_classes = [
        SessionAuthentication,
        TokenAuthentication,
        ]
```

Comment: But it doesn't do any authentication. You are just passing `pass` when you should be authenticating the user

Comment: Dan, this is used in combination with TokenAuthentication. See authentication_classes. When I implemented this solution I remember to have tested it. Will check again.

Comment: Yeah probably my bad. I'm not using `TokenAuthentication`.